# Check if a member is in a certain server Discord BOT javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to setup the command so that whenever the bot receives a direct message from a user, it checks whether if this user in this certain server.

I have the ID for the server, but unable to make it work.

```
  let serverID = "redacted"
  let checkGuild = client.guilds.cache.get(serverID)
  let checkID = msg.author.id
 if (checkGuild.members.cache.find(checkID)){
  }else{
       msg.reply("Not In Server:ERROR")
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide us more informations to identify the problem. For example the shape of `checkGuild` and `checkID` or the error message if you got one

Comment: `find()` accepts a callback function identical to `Array.prototype.find()`. If you have an id you want to use `.get()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `.get()`

```js
let guildID = "GUILD_ID"
let userID = "USER_ID"

let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID)
let member = guild.members.cache.get(userID)
if (!member) return message.reply("He left the server")
// Will return undefined if member does not exist
```